# Intertext in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to use the \intertext latex command inside a Jupyter notebook? Currently when I try to use it, it does not recognise it as a valid latex command.

When I run this:

```
$$
\begin{align*}
\theta_{MAP} &= \argmax\theta p(\theta | \mathcal{D})\\
\intertext{Using Bayes' Theorem:}\\
&= \argmax_\theta \frac{p(\mathcal{D} | \theta) p(\theta)}{p(\mathcal{D})}
\end{align*}
$$
```

I get the following output:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efsa9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook uses MathJax for it's latex parsing, and according to [this issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/736) it's not within the scope of MathJax to support `\intertex`